# Passing SSH options to git-clone

Tags: ssh, git, options

I connect to my server using SSH:

`ssh user@server -p 2224 -zZ abcd`

I also have a git repository on my server. The only way I know to clone is:

`git clone ssh://user@server.com:2224/path/to/repo`

Using the above command I can't connect to my server because `-zZ abcd` is not in the command. I tried the following commands but doesn't work.

`git clone ssh://user@server.com:2224/path/to/repo -zZ abcd`

`git clone "ssh://user@server.com:2224/path/to/repo -zZ abcd"`

How can I include ssh parameters in `git-clone` command?

Comment: Read also [Passing ssh options to git clone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772190/passing-ssh-options-to-git-clone)

Answer (score 5):

You may set up configuration options to save typing; so, after

```
$ cat >>.git/config <<EOF
[remote "myrepo"]
    url = ssh://user@server.com:2224/path/to/repo -zZ abcd
EOF
```

use just `git clone myrepo`

See the explanations of the remote..url options in [git config](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to set per-host ssh options. This can be nice when you want the ssh options to work for all ssh commands and not just for git. These options go in ~/.ssh/config and are documented in `man ssh_config`. For example, ~/.ssh/config might include something like:

```
Host server.com
Compression "yes"
ConnectTimeout 4
GlobalKnownHostsFile /path/to/hosts_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you regularly use a repository then you should do this using `.ssh/config` like amcnabb says, remember that `.ssh/config` lets you make aliases for configuration options, or maybe `.git/config` if that's inappropriate for some reason.

If however you must pass `ssh` really transient config options, like because you're stuck at an airport wifi which blocks `ssh`, then adapt my usual instructions for `ssh` over `tor` :

Install `connect` in your path, maybe by building `connect.c` from source

Create a script called `git-tbb` :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export CONNECT_PASSWORD=""
exec ssh -o ProxyCommand="connect -5 -S 127.0.0.1:9150 %h %p" $*
```

Create a script called `git-tbb`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
export GIT_SSH=`which ssh-tbb` git pull
exec git $*
```

Rename them to `-tor` if you change the port to 9050 for the default tor config, as opposed to TBB's default 9150.